# Can you setup keycloak as an sso that does not use cookies

Tags: keycloak

We have a website using keycloak for SSO to all service API endpoints. It works fine. We want to make or website available in a smartphone app that frames our site in an iframe.
The problem is that in this context all cookies from our website become 3rd party cookies and Intelligent Tracking Protection (Webkit browser engine) blocks them.
Is it possible to set up keycloak to work competely without cookies, just using eg LocalStorage?

Comment: https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/

Comment: This I understood: ITP blocks the cookies but the question then is: can you make keycloak run without cookies?

Comment: Correct, I didn't post it as answer, but only as a comment. That blogpost offer also recommendations how to solve some use cases.